# Pandas dataframe - Setting with copy warning

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series, warnings

I would like to forwardfill an hourly dataframe so that the value for hour 1 gets forwardfilled for every hour 1 on the following days. The same for each of the 24 hours.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
Timestamp   input1  input2  input3
…   …   …   ..
01.01.2018 00:00    2   5   4
01.01.2018 01:00    3   3   2
01.01.2018 02:00    5   6   1
…           
01.01.2018 22:00    2   0   1
01.01.2018 23:00    5   3   3
02.01.2018 00:00    6   2   5
02.01.2018 01:00    3   6   4
02.01.2018 02:00    3   9   6
02.01.2018 03:00    5   1   7
…           
02.01.2018 23:00    2   5   1
03.01.2018 00:00    NaN NaN NaN
…           
03.01.2018 23:00    NaN NaN NaN
```

I am using the following code for this:

```
   for hr in range(0,24):    
   df.loc[df.index.hour == hr, Inputs] = df.loc[df.index.hour == hr, Inputs].fillna(method='ffill')
```

This works.
Unfortunately I am getting a Warning Message:

```
\Python\WPy-3670_32bit\python-3.6.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:543: SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
 self.obj[item] = s
```

How can I solve this, that I do not get a warning anymore?

The resulting df should have the NaNs filled.

Comment: It usually means your dataframe is a part of another dataframe. Did you have `df = other_df.loc[...]` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
 df[df.index.hour == hr] = df[df.index.hour == hr].fillna(method="ffill")
```

Very similar to .loc, but does not tend to raise as many Settingwithcopy warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code and dind't get the mentioned warning (neither any other).

Using *loc* is just the right way to avoid such warning (as said in this message).

Maybe you are using some older version of *Pandas*?
Upgrade to *0.25* if you have an older version and try again.

Another suspicion: Maybe this warning pertains to some **other** instruction
in your code (**without** *loc*)?